# NSString set from a url doesn't read?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am having trouble getting my NSString to read my string that I have set. The play action is hooked to a UIButton  OnTouchDown if it matters.

```
- (IBAction)play {
 if (audioPlayer.playing == NO) {
    urlSong = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/k.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
     [audioPlayer release];
     audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlSong error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
     //if i set this line to stringSong = @"k"; then comment out the next line everything works fine 
     stringSong = [[urlSong lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
     label.text = stringSong;
    AVAudioSession *audiosession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audiosession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];

    [audioPlayer play];
    [start setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
     else
         if ([stringSong isEqualToString:@"k"]){

         label.text = @"audio stopped";
         [audioPlayer stop];
            }

}
```

When I run the code on my iPhone Xcode returns

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

on this line

```
             if ([stringSong isEqualToString:@"k"]){
```

I know this is due to me trying to set the string from the url because when I plainly set my string to 'k' the code executes just fine.

If anybody is wondering the overall point of this, I am trying to have my audio buttons set to stop all other audio when this button is pressed and start the audio assigned to this button which in this case is 'k.mp3'. But if this audio is already playing just to stop playing all audio. Thank you.

Comment: where is stringSong declaration ?

Comment: @Ramshad It is in my .h file as NSString *stringSong; . rmaddy answered my question though. But thank you for trying to help me answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't retaining `stringSong`.

This line:

```
stringSong = [[urlSong lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

Should be:

```
stringSong = [[[urlSong lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension] retain];
```

At some point this needs to be released.

Comment: Alternatively, use ARC (if possible).